# Rasberry Pi signal repeater/extender

Tags: wifi, pi-4, signal

I'm trying to extend the range of a robot that uses UHF or Wi-Fi signal to communicate with its controller with a range of 100 meters.

Is it possible to implement RPi 4 to serve as a signal booster/extender to increase the range?

- Any thoughts I can start with to build my projects would be highly appreciated.
- Doesn't have to be a Pi 4 if there is a better alternative.

I'm still new to the RPi thing and I'm hoping to learn more from this project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a better alternative which has nothing to do with the Pi. Get an RC radio (the one they use to control model cars / boats / aircrafts). Those usually come in form of handheld controllers with sticks and buttons in addition to the transmitter, but there are bare RC transmitters which can be fed values to be transmitted via UART or a similar interface.

Comment: Yes. I am using HC12, which is RC + UART: https://forum.pi-top.com/t/making-a-rpi-pico-based-smart-vehicle-part-2/1104

Comment: Your link shows a privacy error: Your connection is not private

Comment: Gil: Did you mean my link has an arror? https://forum.pi-top.com/t/making-a-rpi-pico-based-smart-vehicle-part-2/1104

Comment: Gil: Thank you for pointing out that my wireless robot project link is bad. Perhaps I can share my RF/RC/UART HC12/nrf24L01+ experience as an answer here. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

*How to do a wireless robot project*

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Answer***

*Part 1 - Introduction*

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) Raspberry Pi Pico RP2040 Programming in MicroPython, Complete Course for Beginners with Examples - Altium Designer 2022mar03 5,513 views
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAGw-08IOSw&t=6s

(2) Read Raspberry Pi Pico onboard temperature sensor - Engr Fahad Send 2022mar16
https://www.electroniclinic.com/read-raspberry-pi-pico-onboard-temperature-sensor/

(3) pico_robot_v01_2022aug0801
https://penzu.com/p/0c1c4b53

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Project Specification v0.1  tlfong01  2022aug06hkt1303*

1. Wireless Network:

   1.1. The wireless network can be a combination of the following :

   1.1.1. BlueTooth 3/4/BLE, WiFi 2/5G, RF (Radio Frequency 433Mhz, 2.4GHz)
2. SBC/MCU, Wireless network modules:

   2.1 Raspberry Pi.

   2.1.1 The SBC/MCU  Rpi can be a combination of the following models:

   2.1.2 Rpi 1, 2A, 2B, 3A, 3B, 4B (1/2/4 GB), Zero, Zero W.

   2.1.3 Rpi Zero, Zero W, Rpi Zero 2, Rpi Zero 2 W.

   2.1.4 Rpi CM3, CM4

   2.1.5 Rpi Pico, Pico W

   2.2. ESP12, ESP32

   2.3. STM32

   2.4. Wireless network modules:

   2.4.1. nRF24L01+

   2.4.2. HC08

   2.4.3. HC12

*/ to continue, ...*

---

*Appendix B - Old project notes on Pico based wireless robot*

[image: HC12 4WD 2022aug0501]

---